# Add 1 month to dates in for loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to add 1 month in due date for every iteration of for loop. Here's my code below.

```
$qt = 3;
$sales_due_date = 2015-09-21;

for($i=0;$i<$qt;$i++){

    $time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($sales_due_date)));

    $due_dates[] = $time;
}
```

The result is

```
Array ( [0] => 2015-10-21 [1] => 2015-10-21 [2] => 2015-11-21)
```

I want the result to be like below

```
Array ( [0] => 2015-09-21 [1] => 2015-10-21 [2] => 2015-11-21)
```

Comment: Then use $i instead of hard code +1 use +$i month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not update the $sales_due_date and so it will always return the same value. Plus, if you want the starting value, you need to change the logic a bit. Perhaps this might work better for you:

```
$qt = 3;
$sales_due_date = "2015-09-21";
// create a time stamp of the date
$time = strtotime($sales_due_date);
for($i=0;$i<$qt;$i++){
    // convert timestamp back to date string
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
    $due_dates[] = $date;
    // move to next timestamp
    $time = strtotime('+1 month', $time)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this should give expected result

```
$qt = 3;
$sales_due_date = "2015-09-21";

for ($i = 0; $i < $qt; $i++) 
{
    $due_dates[] = $sales_due_date;
    $time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($sales_due_date)));
    $sales_due_date = $time;
}
```

`output`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-21
    [1] => 2015-10-21
    [2] => 2015-11-21
)
```

Comment: This will not include the first month in the output.

Comment: It will include, i checked it. i will update with output.

Comment: `$due_dates[] = $sales_due_date;` it will.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$qt = 3;
$sales_due_date = 2015-09-21;
$time="";
for($i=0;$i<$qt;$i++){

    if($time == "")
    {
    $time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($sales_due_date)));
    }
    else{
    $time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($time)));        
    }

    $due_dates[] = $time;
}
```

Comment: Referring to my answer below you should put quotes around the value for $sales_due_date. Also, this version will not include the first month - but that could be fixed by changing the first if() condition